# mapply and two lists

Tags: r, list, apply

I'm trying to use mapply to combine two lists (A and B). Each element is a dataframe.
I'm trying to rbind the dataframes in A to the corresponding dataframes in B. The following returns what I would like in combo1:

```
num = 10
A<-list()
B<-list()
for (j in 1:num){
    A[[j]] <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(1:9),3,3))
    B[[j]] <- as.data.frame(matrix(seq(10:18),3,3))
}

combo1<-list()
for (i in 1:num){
    combo1[[i]] <-rbind(A[[i]], B[[i]])  
}
```

I'm trying to use mapply to do the same, but I can't get it to work:

```
combo2<-list()
combo2<-mapply("rbind", A, B)
```

I was hoping someone could please help me

Comment: The use of `seq` in the specification of A and B might be problematic too. In the first case it is superfluous, and in the second it looks like it will give misleading results. For vector input, `seq_along` gets used.

Answer (score 11):

You were very close!

```
## Make this a more _minimal_ reproducible example
A <- A[1:2]
B <- B[1:2]

## Override default attempt to reduce results to a vector, matrix, or other array
mapply("rbind", A, B, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
# [[1]]
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  4  7
# 2  2  5  8
# 3  3  6  9
# 4  1  4  7
# 5  2  5  8
# 6  3  6  9
# 
# [[2]]
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  4  7
# 2  2  5  8
# 3  3  6  9
# 4  1  4  7
# 5  2  5  8
# 6  3  6  9
```

Comment: Is there any reason to quote the function name rather than just invoke the function directly?  i.e. `mapply(rbind, A, B, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)`

Comment: @Justin -- Not that I know of. (They both work, since that first argument gets processed by `match.fun()`.)